# Heroku PHP memcache Extension

Tags: php, heroku

Is there anyway to use / install the memcache extension for PHP on Heroku? I know people were able to get mongo extension working [here](https://gist.github.com/1288447). Is there anything similar for the memcache extension? This is probably the only thing keeping me from using Heroku at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a PHP SASL Memcache class in
https://github.com/ronnywang/PHPMemcacheSASL

You can use it on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Heroku uses a SASL for memcache authentication. SASL requires [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)  (not [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)) and memcached requires [libmemcached](http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html) installed and on PHP Heroku I don't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the add-on into an application, you should see the credentials/URL in your applications config when run from the command line rubygem:

`heroku config --app my_app`

You can then connect however you need to.